# undefined returned by the some() method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to prevent an object that has a bunch of arrays that will contain objects from having duplicated objects (I know it looks weid but try to see my code below you will understand what I'm saying)

**JavaScript**

```
var UIController = (function() {

  var DOMstrings = {
    inputDay: ".optionList",
    inputTimeF: ".inputTime",
    inputTimeT: ".inputTime2",
    inputText: ".inputText",
    goingToCkecked: ".checkboxx",
    inputBtn: ".add__btn",
    planContainer: ".container",
    errorCase: ".error-case",
    optionList: ".optionList",
    optionListId: "#optionList",
    errorDes: "error-description",
  };


  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return {
        inputDay: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputDay).value,
        inputTimeF: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputTimeF).value,
        inputTimeT: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputTimeT).value,
        inputText: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputText).value,
        goingToCkecked: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.goingToCkecked).checked,


      };
    },
    getDOMstrings: function() {
      return DOMstrings;
    },



  };

})(); //END OF THE UICONTROLLER MODULE




var internalController = (function(UICtrl) {

  var Plan = function(id, from, to, text, goingToCkecked) {
    this.id = id;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.text = text;
    this.goingToCkecked = goingToCkecked;
  };

  var data = {
    Monday: [],
    Tuesday: [],
    Wednesday: [],
    Thursday: [],
    Friday: [],
    Saturday: [],
    Sunday: []
  };

  function hasObject( day, object ) {
      const dataset = data[day];

// console.log(object.inputTimeF);
      return dataset.some(el => {
          return (
            console.log(el.inputTimeF)
//el.inputTimeF=== object.inputTimeF
              // el.to === object.to
              // el.txt === object.txt
          );
      });
  }

  var Dom = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

return {


    addItem: function(day, from, to, text, goingToCkecked) {
      var newPlan, ID;


      //CREATE NEW ID
      if (data[day].length > 0) {
        ID = data[day][data[day].length - 1].id + 1;
      } else {
        ID = 0;
      }

      //CREATE NEW PLAN BASED ON THE PICKED DAY

      if (day === "Monday" || day === "Tuesday" || day === "Wednesday" || day === "Thursday" || day === "Friday" || day === "Saturday" || day === "Sunday") {
        newPlan = new Plan(ID, from, to, text, goingToCkecked);
      }



      //PUSH IT INTO OUR DATA STRUCTURE
      data[day].push(newPlan);

      //RETURN THE NEW ELEMENT
      return newPlan;

    }, //END OF THE ADD ITEM METHOD


    duplicatedObject: function(day,object) {
      return hasObject(day,object);
    }


  }; //end of the return object of the internal controller module


})(UIController);





var controller = (function(interCtrl, UICtrl) {
  var input, newPlan, DOM;

  DOM = UICtrl.getDOMstrings();

  function setupEventListeners() {

    document.querySelector(DOM.inputBtn).addEventListener("click", ctrlAddPlans);

    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.activeElement.blur();
        ctrlAddPlans();
      }
    });

  }

  var ctrlAddPlans = function() {


    //3.get the filed input data
    input = UICtrl.getInput();
    // console.log(input);


    //5.add the plan to the internalController
    newPlan = interCtrl.addItem(input.inputDay, input.inputTimeF, input.inputTimeT, input.inputText, input.goingToCkecked);

    // 4.Refuse duplicated plans
    var res = interCtrl.duplicatedObject(input.inputDay, input);
    console.log(res)

  };

  return {
    init: function() {
      console.log('the app has started');
      setupEventListeners();
    },

  };
})(internalController, UIController);


controller.init();
```

that big object is the `data` object and he has a bunch of `arrays` as you are seeing and these arrays will contain `objects` from some inputs that the user will input.

So when I'm trying to tackle this problem(I don't wanna any array to have duplicated object)  I'm using the `some()` method (try to see the has object function in my code above).

I'm comparing the `object`'s from parmeter and the `el`'s `from` parameter but I'm getting always `false` as a returned value so when I tried to debug my code I found that the `el.inputTimeF` is returning undefined

**screenshot** 
[image]

I googled this but I didn't found anything useful

Comment: Have you checked exactly what `el` is? Is it the object you expect?

Comment: `console.log()` return `undefined`, that's why

Comment: @hindmost but the *return value* of `console.log` is never itself logged. Not in the code shown, at least

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `el.inputTimeF` is not `undefined` then you can chage your code like the following:

```
return dataset.some(el => {
     return el.inputTimeF;
});
```

Last, do not return `console.log` because it will return `undefined`.

Comment: If `el.inputTimeF` is `undefined`, then `return el.inputTimeF;` would matter little

Comment: I updated my answer, but I'm pretty sure that el.inputTimeF has value! ;)

Comment: It's unclear from the code shown but it *seems like* it doesn't. Can't say for sure, though. OP seems to think it is `undefined`.

Comment: So, my explaination is wrong? If so, It's probably better to delete it

Comment: When he does console.log the value, it says undefined in the console. If you follow the stack in his code, you'll see that he logs the result of some(), which is false unless one condition is met.

Comment: To be fair, OP hasn't provided us with enough data to know what's wrong. OP claims `el.inputTimeF` is `undefined` and a screenshot shows `undefined` logged but we have no way of knowing if the log is correct or not. If the real code is *similar* to what is shown, then that would be correct. But there is no way of verifying - the code is not enough to know to say for sure.

Comment: @MedAmineElwere, see the result of el by doing console.log(el)

Comment: @MedAmineElwere yes, something that can reproduce the behaviour you show. Right now, we don't know what `el` inside `.some` even is.